# Convert 2003 excel File to 2007 using macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2003, vba

I have a 2003 excel file, I wish to convert that file to a 2007 excel file in the same location of the excel file and delete the 2003 file.

Please let me know if this is possible

```
Function ConvertTo2007AndDelete (OldExcelFile As Workbook) As Workbook
     'Code goes here
End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use 'Windows Script Host' to delete files, I'm sure that there is an easier way.

but here is all I had to do to take an open 2003 spreadsheet and save it as 2007

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Administrator.CLPOINT\Desktop\CSC1.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: But how do I keep the file name and file location?

Comment: Since the file extension changes from .xls to .xlsx, do you also need a line to delete the old .xls file? Or does the CreateBackkup:=False take care of that?

Comment: 10x for the help, I understand deleting the file can be easy using the windows commands,
But I guess that my problem is how do I know the full file path and the path name.